# Mishnah Berura: Saying Korbanos

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, mishnah-berurah, korbanos-ketores-prayers

When the Mishnah Berura wants to explain why we say Korbanos every day he writes in [1:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.1.13?vhe=Wikitext&lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en):

> ופרשת הקרבנות, דאמרינן במנחות: "זאת תורת החטאת", כל העוסק בתורת חטאת כאילו הקריב חטאת.‏
>
> and the paragraph of Korbanos, as we say in Menachos: "this is the instruction of the Chatas", everyone who delves into the instruction of the Chatas is as if he offered a Chatas

But later on [in 48:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.48.1?vhe=eu5_text&lang=bi) he writes:

> וכן כתבו הספרים דמה שאמר הגמרא כל העוסק בפרשת עולה וכו' הכוונה שהוא מתעסק להבין עניניה לא אמירת התיבות לבד
>
> and so books wrote: that which the Gemara says "everyone who delves into the paragraph of the Olah etc.", [its] intention is that he is delving to understand its topic, not [performing] the utterance of the words alone

Isn't this a contradiction, for when one reads Korbanos even with understanding he isn't a מתעסק?

Comment: Where in the _MB_ are these? Can you [edit] the citations in to the question, please?

Comment: How is reading Korbanos with understanding not מתעסק? What do you think מתעסק means?

Comment: @DoubleAA  whats needed is מתעסק להבין עניניה

Answer (score 1):

When taken in context, there no contradiction at all.

The first time he mentions (merely saying) it (in [1:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.1.13?vhe=Wikitext&lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en)) it is a comment on Shulchan Aruch 1:5. This follows the 7-word [1:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.1.13?vhe=Wikitext&lang=bi&p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) which teaches us:

> טוב מעט תחנונים בכוונה מהרבות בלא כוונה:‏
>
> Better few supplications with concentration than much without concentration.

So there is no need for the Mishna Berura to repeat in 1:5 that merely mouthing the words has little to no effect.

By the time you get to [48:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.48.1?vhe=eu5_text&lang=bi) you may no longer remember this rule. :-)